# CMake: static library include directory propagation

Tags: c++, cmake

Let's suppose that I have a dynamic library and I want to link a static library against it with `target_link_libraries`. I also have a `CMakeLists` for both and a `Find<PACKAGE>.cmake` for the static library for Win. In Linux setup it's presumably done by Conan.
The files of the static library are not all situated in one directory (say, `src`) – some of them are, but other files – both sources and headers – are situated in **subfolders** or `src`. The static library is compiled and built with no errors.

 
 When the dynamic library is being compiled, I get "include not found" errors using gcc, but MSVC does perfect (probably, because it exposes include directories via `INTERFACE` modifier, like I described in question one? Anyways, necessary paths are added automatically, without further ado). I have the following questions:

1. Will something along the lines of `target_include_directories(target_name INTERFACE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})` suffice to avoid errors (now it is `PRIVATE`) or should I list all subfolders (there are no `CMakeLists` in any of them and making a library out any of them doesn't seem quite correct)? Should I use `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` instead of `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`?
2. Do I understand correctly that headers are not necessary to be listed for a correct build of a library?
3. Should I use absolute paths in `#include` directives for those files which are situated in subfolders if I expose only the `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` (i. e. the top-level folder with `CMakeLists` inside)?
4. Which modifier (`PRIVATE`, `INTERFACE`, `PUBLIC`) should be used in `target_link_libraries`?

    I've searched throughout the Internet and SO but I haven't come across a **direct** answer to any of the question above, considering my setup, so, please, don't mark the question a dupe.

Comment: 2. Yes you don't need to list headers for add_libarary or add_executable. However listing them helps some IDEs like Visual Studio Community.

Comment: 4. Depends on your use case. These all mean different things.

Comment: 3. I usually use relative paths to a `target_include_directories( libraryTarget PUBLIC libIncludeFolder)` setting.

Comment: "I have the following questions" - One **question** per **question post**, please.

Comment: @drescherjm, thank you very much! What about the question 1? Any guesses?

Comment: To be honest I have not used INTERFACE yet. I don't know. I use PUBLIC or PRIVATE many times.